# Creating custom CCK Field Types in Drupal

Tags: drupal, cck

I've been trying to get this module to work and no matter what I've tried I can't seem to get this to show up in the "Add Field" selection box, full code is over here:

http://drupalbin.com/11854

The gist follows, I have the following hooks implemented:

```
function uc_product_content_install() {

}

function uc_product_content_uninstall() {

}

function uc_product_content_enable() {

}

function uc_product_content_disable() {

}

function uc_product_content_field_info() {

}

function uc_product_content_field_settings($op, $field) {

}

function uc_product_content_field($op, &$node, $field, &$items, $teaser, $page) {

}

function uc_product_content_is_empty($item, $field) {

}

function uc_product_content_field_formatter_info() {

}

function uc_product_content_default_value(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $delta) {
}

function uc_product_content_widget(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $items, $delta = 0) {

}
```

Comment: The naming convention looks like the one used by the ubercart module - are you using that and it does not work or are you writing this yourself?

Comment: I'm writing my own module that provides enhanced functionality above that provided by UC Node Checkout.  That module only allows one product to be associated with a node, this module will allow multiple products to be associated and chosen via a CCK field.

I'm doing my best to follow the Ubercart convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the above hooks, I defined the following:

```
function uc_product_content_widget_info() {

}

function uc_product_content_widget_settings($op, $widget) {

}
```

And now it's showing up as a field, so I can continue working on it.